# Converting SQL Server database to SQL Server Compact edition file (.sdf) version 3.0

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server-ce

I'm currently creating a solution for a software that were developed in 2005 and beside using some more modern technologies, the company wants to keep supports of the old windows embedded compact edition based phones until they can replace everything.

I tried using ErikEJ's Export2SQLCE and SqlCEcmd command tools and thought I found the solution, until I realised the older application is using SQL Server CE version 3.0, whereas ErikEJ's can only convert to 3.5 or 4.

Is there any way to convert an existing SQL Server table into SQL Server CE version 3.0?

If not, is there any way to connect into a SQL Server CE file (`.sdf`) from a nodejs server and send queries?

Thanks!

Comment: Update your solution to use 3.5 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant.
The solution is something old, that is currently running on 400 different devices around the world, and the company would rather not ask them to get sent back just to update the solution.

keep in mind that its really old, and the newer solution involves an express server with a react client, this is just to enable usage of the older devices until they are disposed

Comment: It should be possible to re-build SQLceCMD against 3.1.